# GWT module [name] may need to be (re)compiled error

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

Installed latest Eclipse (Luna) and added latest GWT plugin (no Maven), any GWT project that I try to run in Eclipse gives the same error

GWT module [name] may need to be (re)compiled.

Tried the projects that worked in older versions of eclipse before, same error.

Tried deleting ALL generated files/cache files and clearing browser cache, as per old Stackoverflow recommendations.

Tried different versions of JDK.

Tried reinstalling everything from scratch, creating new workspace and new empty project using web-app Eclipse wizard,  the same result.

No errors in logs.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually an issue in cached compiled files. Try this:

- Delete the content of the folder /war/[application name]
- Clear the browser cache
- Delete the content of gwt-unitCache folder
- In Eclipse : Project > clean...
- Compile the application : right click on the project > Google > GWT compile

Edit

GWT also create some files in the temp folder of the OS. Assuming you're using Windows, run this [batch script](https://gist.github.com/moutellou/fbeca1a5dabdea591835#file-gistfile1-bat) that I use sometimes to cleanup GWT cache.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, done all that many times, including erasing entire environment and the projects themselves from the disc completely and installing everything from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, but I cleaned up the Temp dir too, doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by deleting everything, installing a new GWT 2.7 and launching the project in super-dev mode. Apparently, unless you launch in supr-dev mode, correct Javascript is not generated at all.

Comment: I was stuck with this enoying popup (GWT module [name] may need to be (re)compiled) when i go to to my web app using the browser. So when i ran the code in super-dev mode all was working fine. Thank you for your answer really helped me.